# How to find the code for Google account authentication button on login page of super user or other SE site?

Tags: support

I usually use Google Account authentication to login SE. But, I can not find bigger size of Account authentication button on the contents of https://superuser.com recently and sometimes.
I believe there are more than three major site account button to authenticate with SE site such Google Account. So, I confirmed these existed on Chrome web view of Android Smartphone. It might work if I use small button of Google but I will have to put my account and password.

- Chrome version 33.0.1750.146
- OS X 10.9.2

**Question:**

1. Could you tell me the code for Log in using Google Account with
   bigger size of button?
2. How it will be authenticated with Google
   Account and SE authentication on my chrome?

I will be able to compare it with I grab it using curl in my end.

This is what I had a contents of same log in link on superuser.com and did not propaget my ID and password of my Google account.

[image]

This is what I had a contents of same log in link on superuser.com just before.(Seems be Successfully get contents and I could login like this without any problem.)

[image]

Comment: It says "Log in using Google" right there. The first option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're asking here.

- The login using Google is visible
- The "big" buttons are shown for Login to site - for adding logins the one you see in the picture is the one.

Are you trying to ask if you can get the one with the buttons on the add login screen too?

It might be that the team is revisiting the login page at a later point of time

Comment: My question is why it's different contents I will get sometimes even it's same link on Google Search.